# how to implement a explode function in a table in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have comma based string which is separated by comma, i need the staring to be converted in each single row and add against to the id ,how should i rotate the inner loop for code after explode function

> ```
> <?php $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");    if($conn->connect_error){
> die("Connection Failed<br>".$conn->connect_error); }
>
>
>      $sql = 'SELECT id,mobile,code,createdon FROM tset';
>      $result = $conn->query($sql);
>                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
>                               $id = $row['id'];
>                               $mobile = $row['mobile'];
>                               $code = $row['code'];                                   
>                               $date = $row['date'];
>                               echo "<tr><td>".$id."</td><td>".$mobile."</td>
>                               <td>".$code."</td><td>".$date."</td></tr>";
>
>                           }
>      mysqli_close($conn);  ?>
> ```

Sample Data
id:10542
Mobile: 1234567890
Code: H5413910102,H5413910201,H5413910301,H5413910701,H5413910802,
dateL:2017-08-30 16:57:00

I need to get the data in this format by using the sample data

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>MOBILE</th>
<th>CODE</th>
<th>DATE</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10541</td><td>1234567890</td><td>H5413910102</td><td>9/4/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10541</td><td>1234567890</td><td>H5413910201</td><td>9/4/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10541</td><td>1234567890</td><td>H5413910301</td><td>9/4/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10541</td><td>1234567890</td><td>H5413910701</td><td>9/4/2017</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>10541</td><td>1234567890</td><td>H5413910802</td><td>9/4/2017</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
$myString = "H5413910102,H5413910201,H5413910301,H5413910701,H5413910802,";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString); 

foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
    echo $my_Array.'<br>';   
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to Explode the "Code" field from the Db?

Comment: I have update the code ,In this way i have tried@KetanSolanki

Comment: Have you tried the code which I have written below? And please consider "Normalization" of the database as mentioned by @rajdeep paul.

Comment: Yes both of the codes mentioned by both of your are working

Comment: i have used comma based because we get the data in lakhs of rows so when use each single row for a product then it will be late while fetching the records from db so i used this method

Comment: Am getting an empty row in the table due to the comma which is at the last value how to remove that

Comment: Ok Sairam, in this case, its better to do the processing through PHP rather than joining another table.

Comment: i didn't get you @KetanSolanki

Comment: ok use rtrim function once to get rid off the last , like this : $myString = rtrim($myString,","); and then explode this string

Comment: while joining the code with other table no data is retrieving , am getting the name of the code from other table when am using join then no data is obtained ,how can i override it?@KetanSolanki

Comment: Please add what query you are using in which you are getting no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code helps you :

```
 $sql = 'SELECT id,mobile,code,createdon FROM tset';
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $mobile = $row['mobile'];
      $code = $row['code'];                                   
      $date = $row['date'];
      $code = explode(",",$code);
      foreach($code as $key=>$value){
         echo "<tr><td>".$id."</td><td>".$mobile."</td><td>".$value."</td><td>".$date."</td></tr>";
      }                              
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the database's perspective, it's not recommended and certainly not a good practice to have data as comma separated list. You should consider [**normalizing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database. Having said that, you should follow the below procedure to achieve the desired result as of now(or for the time being).

```
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");    
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed<br>".$conn->connect_error); 
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT id,mobile,code,createdon FROM tset';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>MOBILE</th>
            <th>CODE</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $codes = explode(",", $row['code']);
        foreach($codes as $code){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $code; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    mysqli_close($conn);  
?>
```